# How to make an android raised button?

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-button

Ii have been searching in web for a week or so to get an example or tutorial on how to make a coloured raised button but no luck.

I want the following to be implemented in my app for better User interface experience.

And i did come across with the card view but when you write a big program with lots of buttons in it, the xml code will get bigger just because of this card view.

So if there is any quick and simple solution to the following please let me know.

Thank you

[image]

**updated**

```
            Normal button
```

[image]

```
and with color
```

[image]

Comment: Use the default Material `Button` style, set the backgroundTint to blue (or a color state list with grey for the disabled state) and the foreground to `?android:attr/textColorPrimaryInverse`.

Comment: @alanv but to get the ripple, one has to use `"?attr/selectableItemBackground"` on the foreground

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you actually want elevation in button. Don't use card as it require more resources. for lollipop devices use

```
<Button
    ...
    android:stateListAnimator="@anim/my_animator" />
```

and in anim folder in resources create my_animator.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:state_enabled="true">
        <set>
            <objectAnimator android:propertyName="translationZ"
                            android:duration="@integer/button_pressed_animation_duration"
                            android:valueTo="@dimen/button_pressed_z_material"
                            android:valueType="floatType"/>
            <objectAnimator android:propertyName="elevation"
                            android:duration="0"
                            android:valueTo="@dimen/button_elevation_material"
                            android:valueType="floatType"/>
        </set>
    </item>
    <!-- base state -->
    <item android:state_enabled="true">
        <set>
            <objectAnimator android:propertyName="translationZ"
                            android:duration="@integer/button_pressed_animation_duration"
                            android:valueTo="0"
                            android:startDelay="@integer/button_pressed_animation_delay"
                            android:valueType="floatType"/>
            <objectAnimator android:propertyName="elevation"
                            android:duration="0"
                            android:valueTo="@dimen/button_elevation_material"
                            android:valueType="floatType" />
        </set>
    </item>
    ...
</selector>
```

Comment: it worked but showing the following error:::

**Couldn't resolve resource @integer/button_pressed_animation_duration (5 similar errors not shown) "@integer/button_pressed_animation_duration" in attribute "duration" is not a valid integer (5 similar errors not shown)**

how do you make it a coloured button

Comment: Please update me with the dimen values used and the integer values used.. and how do you put colour to the button just like the android raised button

Comment: OK these error are just for dimension and integer values ..in integer use some value between 100 - 400 and in dimension use 2dp - 6dp.

Comment: what about the color?

Comment: Raised button don't have any special color, they have a 3rd dimention out of screen which give them some shadow's and above the screen type of feelings. But to change color of your button you can use   <shape 
    >  
    <solid
        android:color="@color/dark_white" />
</shape> in my_animator

Comment: I have edited the above comment look again. also have a look at material design guidelines, it will surely help you in your UI design understanding http://www.google.com/design/spec/material-design/introduction.html#. You MUST check out the following link its very awesome.

Comment: i think when it had error it was looking better then :P the look and feel is not there once i have updated with the integer and animation

Comment: did you put  <shape > <solid android:color="#fff" /> </shape> inside <set> </set> ?  and use proper values in dimen and integer it should work

Comment: yes i did as you said but its not showing up the colour

Comment: Remove duration and delay if not require ..and for state pressed use elevation value 4dp and for base state use elevation value 2dp according to your need

Comment: also getting this error when put the shape within set

**rendering error unknown animator name : shape**

Comment: ok remove shape. You can simply use android:background = "#your color " . Hope this will help this time :)

Comment: where do i use the following?

Comment: In your main xml under <Btton></Button>

Comment: i have updated with the output please check moreover on putting the colour i can't see any effect on click

Comment: ok this is because background changes the default background of your button. You can use custom background in same way as you changed stateListAnimator. See this site it may help you to create your button background http://angrytools.com/android/button/

Comment: You can use duration as
                android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"

Comment: <selector tag is not supported in anim folder

Answer (score 6):

You can try this alternative:
Create a `xml` in your **drawable** folder:
cardlayout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <gradient android:angle="90"
                android:endColor="@color/background_gray" android:startColor="#ccc" />
            <corners android:radius="4dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item
        android:left="0dp"
        android:right="1.5dp"
        android:top="0dp"
        android:bottom="1.5dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/white"/>
            <corners android:radius="4dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Now any `view` (Button, ListRow or imageView) you want to elevate. Just set the background of that view using this cardlayout.

```
android:background="@drawable/cardlayout"
```

NB change the cardlayouts background color according to your need.

Comment: a thing of beauty!

Answer (score 3):

Check this out:-

```
<Button
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:text="Raised Color Button"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:backgroundTint="#1E9D96"
    android:textColor="@android:color/background_light" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use : 
    `android:elevation="2dp"`

But it will only work for Lollipop and above. I suggest using a layerlist in case of lower versions of Android.